# Google Drive New Location "Access Denied"

Tags: terminal, google-apps

Google Released an update to its Desktop app for macOS which moved the location of your files to "~/Library/CloudStorage"

I host scripts in a Google Shared Drive and since this move "Terminal" or "iTerm" cannot run commands from the scripts as terminal spits out a "zsh: permission denied" Error.

Permissions allow for "Full Disk Access" of Terminal and iTerm and no restrictions to stop access.

Any ideas?
[image: iTerm Screenshot]

Comment: What are the permissions of the file/directory of the script you're trying to run?

Comment: What xattr does the file have? I am wondering about quarantine flag being set when the files were moved.